# Facebook like View below navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

Which is the best way to create Facebook like | Status | Photo | Check in | bar below navigation bar, I have to put a segment over there and my view will change according to the segment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a ViewController add a  three buttons for  status, photo, checkin.
Then drag a ContainerView into the ViewController. Then, Connect each tabs (status, photo, checkin) for different ViewControllers in containerView.

For switching the viewControllers for tabs cyclic switching ViewController code available in Apple Documents also.

Hope this will helps you.